# how to resizing X-label text size in MPandroidCharts

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPandroidCharts in android application to make a bar chart it data from NodeJs server my code works fine but I found that when I change nbs of data (number of articles "on XAxe" < 5) the label nb and size still the some ( max 5 elements)  that make my graph Not understood, I need a solution plz

to understand my situation plz look at pictures:

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            final ArrayList<String> months = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.d("liste size ",product_List.size()+"");
            for(int i=0; i<product_List.size();i++){
                Log.d("get List nb ",product_List.get(i).getId());
                Log.d("get List produit ",product_List.get(i).getProduit());
                months.add(i,product_List.get(i).getProduit());
                int nb = Integer.parseInt(product_List.get(i).getId());
                entries.add(new BarEntry(i, nb));

            }
            BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "Produits");
            barDataSet.setBarBorderWidth(0.9f);
            barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
            BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
            XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
            xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

            IndexAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IndexAxisValueFormatter(months);
            xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
            xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
            barChart.setData(barData);
            barChart.setFitBars(true);
            barChart.animateY(5000);
            barChart.invalidate();
```

One more thing, if I when to clear chart data and make others by a button which code I need to use.

Comment: try this barChart.setExtraBottomOffset(5);, Hope this will work!

Comment: nope, thanks but it doesn't work